# Bridging networks issue

Tags: networking, bridge, bridge-router

The architecture is:

```
[  Router 1   ]              [   Router 2    ]              [   Router 3    ]
[ aDSL Router ]---UtpCable---[wireless router]---UtpCable---[wireless router]
[192.168.1.254]              [  192.168.1.1  ]              [  192.168.1.2  ]
```

`Router 1` is the only one to act as a modem as well as a router.

`Routers 1` and `Router 2` connect without a problem and each broadcast their own wifi signal and clients can connect to them without a problem.

`Router 2`, which is wired to `Router 1`, runs on a `bridged mode` and `DHCP relay`.

This is the configuration for `Router 2`:

[image]

Everything up to that point works fine. Wireless (and wired) clients can connect to both `Router 1` and `Router 2` without a problem.

Now I'm trying to extend this network by wiring `Router 3` to one of `Router 2`'s switch ports and create another bridge with the same configuration as `Router 2`.

When I connect a client to `Router 3`'s wifi I get an `IP` of `169.254.*` and when I change my wireless adapter's settings I get an `IP` of `192.168.1.*` but I cannot `ping` `Router 2` (`192.168.1.1`) or `Router 1` (`192.168.1.254`) and obviously I don't have an internet connection.

What am I missing here?

**Solution**: The UTP cable that connected `Router 2` to `Router 3` was very long, replacing it with a shorter one resolved all issues.

Comment: sounds like Router3 is acting like a router, not a bridge. are routers 2 and 3 of the same make/model? also, does router1 start its dhcp pool at 100 as specified in your relay config?

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks for your answer. Routers 2 and 3 are exactly the same model (but slightly different firmware, like a version away). Regarding the DHCP, according to my understanding Router 2 justs relays Router 1's DHCP rules so the `starting IP = 100` would only matter if Router 2 was acting as an active DHCP server, for example the client I'm using right now is wirelessly connected to Router 2 and has an automatic IP of:  192.168.1.7

Comment: I agree, but the UI is ambigious on that point, so without testing, there is the possibility that it is filtering addresses > 100 from being relayed. just a thought. have you confirmed a valid WAN address on R3?

Comment: @FrankThomas it was the UTP cable that connected R1 to R2. I appreciate your efforts.